# How to rewrite double sum in matrix operation?

Tags: summation, transformation

I have a double sum $\sum_{i=1,j=1}^n \alpha_i \alpha_j y_i y_j(x_i,x_j),\ x_i \in R^{d},\ y_i \in R,\ \alpha_i \in R $

How it can be rewritten in terms of vectors and matrices operations?

Comment: If the $y_{i}$ and $\alpha_{i}$ are just real scalars, why keep them separate? What is $(x_{i},x_{j})$?

Comment: $(x_i,x_j)$ is dot product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the matrix whose columns are $x_i$, and let $y$ be the (column) vector whose entries are $\alpha_i y_i$.  Your sum can be written as
$$
y^T X^TX y
$$

Answer (score 0):

consider the following expressions, may be they are helpful.

$\mathbf{\alpha}=[\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n]^T$

$\mathbf{\alpha}\mathbf{\alpha}^T$

$\mathbf{y}\mathbf{y}^T$

$X^TX$

$X=\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{x_1}^T\\ 
\mathbf{x_2}^T
\end{bmatrix}$

I assume $(x_i,x_j)$ is the dot product of the two vectors.